# track tag in html is always showing : unsafe attempt to load url.. What is wrong?

Tags: html

I am trying to use track tag to put a subtitle to my video. First of all the captions button is available and once I click it disappears and the inspect shows me an error appearing on the right.
[image: the error]

This is my simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <video controls >
        <source src="photos/c.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <track src="c.vtt>" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="english">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and include error messages as text, not as an image of text.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure "c.vtt>" is not a valid file name...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's because Chrome and Edge prohibit HTML files accessing VTT files from a local drive, and I have yet to find a simple and easy fix for this issue. It works perfectly fine on Internet Explorer though.